# Changing array size changes the behaviour of STRCMP

Tags: c, arrays

My program checks a given 4 bit hash from file HashedPassword.txt and compares it to all possible 4 upper-case letter possibilities which is supposed to be in temp.txt.

My issue is that my program works fine if my array "alpha" is of size 13 and under, in this case my program will hit the STRCMP if statement and give me the correct password that corresponds to the hash given in HashedPasswords.txt, anything above size 13 array will cause STRCMP to print out none stop "1" therefore not finding a match.'

How can I fix this?

P.S I tried changing the sizes of line and line2, making them larger changes the output of strcmp as well.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void E(char *in, char *out);

int main()
{
    FILE* file,*fp2,*fp3;
    char input[5];
    char pass[5];
    char alpha[15]="ABCD";//EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    char compare;
    char string[5];
    int i,j,k,l,m,a;

    size_t lsize=0;
    char line[5];
    char line2[5];
    char output[5];
    char newline[2]="\n";
    char test[5];
    char *r=NULL;

    fp2=fopen("HashedPassword.txt","r");

    fgets(line2,sizeof(line2),fp2);

    printf("%s\n",line2);

    fclose(fp2);
    file=fopen("temp.txt","w");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {

        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<4;k++)
            {
                for(l=0;l<4;l++)
                {
                    fprintf(file,"%c%c%c%c\n",alpha[i],alpha[j],alpha[k],alpha[l]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    fp3=fopen("temp.txt","r");

    while(getline(&r,&lsize,fp3))
    {
        E(r,output);

        printf("%d\n",strcmp(output,line2));

        if(!strcmp(output,line2))
        {
            printf("This is your password: %s\n",r);
            break;
    }

    }

    fclose(fp3);
}


void E(char *in, char *out)
{
    out[0]=(in[0]&0x80)^(((in[0]>>1)&0x7F)^((in[0])&0x7F));
    out[1]=((in[1]&0x80)^((in[0]<<7)&0x80))^(((in[1]>>1)&0x7F)^((in[1])&0x7F));
    out[2]=((in[2]&0x80)^((in[1]<<7)&0x80))^(((in[2]>>1)&0x7F)^((in[2])&0x7F));
    out[3]=((in[3]&0x80)^((in[2]<<7)&0x80))^(((in[3]>>1)&0x7F)^((in[3])&0x7F));
}
```

Comment: what do you think strcmp does and what example data are you reading from fp and where is that stored?

Comment: strcmp checks if 2 strings are equal, if they are it prints out a 0 otherwise it prints out the difference. I'm just reading in a hash of the the password BACD using the hash function below.

Comment: caâæ, my program returns BACD and any other variations, only when the array size is less than 13, therefore my limit is 13 letters but I need 26 to cover all options

Comment: What data are you reading in ? Are all lines less than 5 characters? and why is alpha[15] ? better char * alpha as it will get the size from the string

Comment: I'm reading in caâæ, the hash of BACD. 15 was just a random size I was trying when I realized that the array size was messing around with strcmp's output

Comment: What is output[4] ? As not '\0' then strcmp will not know where to end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing: `output` is of length 5 but you only ever set the first four characters in `E()` which means that `output[4]` contains random garbage (whatever happened to be in that particular byte of memory). `strcmp` compares two null terminated strings so you should make sure that `ouput[4] = '\0'` is done at least once. It would also be slightly better to use `strncmp` and provide the length (e.g. `strncmp(output, line2, sizeof(output))` to make sure it doesn't go completely wild in case of missing null termination.

Changing the size of the local variables around will affect where exactly on the stack `output` is located which will affect what the content of `output[4]` is which will affect the result of the `strcmp`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I'll be sure to keep this in mind next time I come across arrays